# c++ Windows Forms.Как написать обработчик клика по кнопке в основном файле .cpp?

Tags: windows, winforms, visual-studio, c++-cli

Создал visual studio c++ clr проект(test5).При двойном клике по кнопке обработчик клика создается в заголовочном файле MyForm.h и писать там код не правильно.

MyForm.h

```
       ...
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button1_Click);
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this->label1->AutoSize = true;
            this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(116, 135);
            this->label1->Name = L"label1";
            this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(35, 13);
            this->label1->TabIndex = 1;
            this->label1->Text = L"label1";
            // 
            // MyForm
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(284, 262);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Name = L"MyForm";
            this->Text = L"MyForm";
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }

    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
        {

        };
    };
}
```

MyForm.cpp

```
#include "MyForm.h"

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

    [STAThreadAttribute]
    void Main(array<String^>^ args) {
        Application::EnableVisualStyles();
        Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        test5::MyForm form;
        Application::Run(%form);
    }
```

Comment: Где создаётся, там и правильно писать.

Comment: Ничто не запрещает вынести код в файл cpp. В h оставить только определение метода. Как вам удобнее. / Сам язык C++/CLI является чем-то второстепенным. И поддержка WinForms сделана абы как, лишь бы было. Поэтому не стоит ожидать правильной архитектуры от автосгенерированного кода.

Answer (score 0):

Ваше утверждение о том, что "не правильно" писать код там, куда его написала автогенерация, весьма сомнительно. Да, в классическом подходе основной код пишется в `.cpp`-файлах, однако, если Вы работаете в контексте фреймворка, то следует придерживаться правил, навязанных им. Следовательно, писать код там, куда его изначально помещает система автоматической генерации, более чем правильно.